# CSS Background Image loads the half-size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem, in CSS I included an image as background but it load or show just the half size...

My Code:

CSS:

```
html, body { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 

#background
{ background-image: url("../img/background.png"); }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div class="container">
             <?php include("template/navigation.php"); ?> 

                <?php
                if(isset($_GET["page"])) $page = $_GET["page"];
                    else $page = "home";
                if(file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.php'))
                    include('pages/'.$page.'.php');
                else include("pages/home.php");
                ?>
            </div>         
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I try to change the background-size, but nothing happens.
If I use height it looks awfull...
Can someone helps me?

This is how it looks now, but I want that the Image has the full height...
[image]

Comment: have you tried setting `height: 100%` or `min-height: 100%` on the `#background` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to assign the background to your body:

```
body { background-image: url("../img/background.png"); }
```

or, give `#background` more height:

```
#background{ height: 100vh; background-image: url("../img/background.png");}
```

It's a div, and it's only as tall as the content inside it.

Comment: Oh thank's for your Help!
I forgot that a div is just so tall as the content is ^^